# Django : mail_admins() doesn't works

Tags: django

I try to use mail_admins() instead of send_mail (it's works) but it doesn't works...

My view :

```
...
if request.method == "POST":
    form = contactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sujet = form.cleaned_data['sujet']
        message= form.cleaned_data['message']
        try:
            mail_admins(subject=sujet, message=message)
...
```

My settings :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "zor@gmail.com"
SERVER_EMAIL = "zor@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "zor@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mdp_of_zor@gmail.com"
```

Why I don't receive message in this adress (zor@gmail.com) ??

Comment: Do you have ADMINS setting defined?

Comment: quoting the docs "django.core.mail.mail_admins() is a shortcut for sending an email to the site admins, as defined in the ADMINS setting"

Comment: ADMINS setting ? I don't know what is this setting...

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS

Comment: what is your `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting ?

Comment: So Mad is right, I had ADMINS=[...] but now I have a new error SMTPAuthenticationError because Gmail blocked my site connexion

Comment: @Zoulou i hope that isn't your gmail password in your code there! likely Gmail has now locked/blocked that account as it would have been used to send out a great deal of spam.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Its a good practice to use `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` in production server, and `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` in development.

Comment: I added this, but it doesn't works... I receive a message in Gmail from Google : "... Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account zor@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards. ... "